# Tail of increasing convergent net of self-adjoint operators is bounded

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, nets, self-adjoint-operators, strong-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $(T_\alpha)$ an [increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element) net of self-adjoint operators that converges (in some topology) to an operator $T$. Then $(T_\alpha)$ is not necessarily norm-bounded I think (is this correct?). Assuming that the index set is non-empty, for any $\alpha_0$ we can consider the net $(T_\alpha)_{\alpha\geq\alpha_0}$. I want to prove that this net is actually norm-bounded. I think that $T_{\alpha_0}\leq T_\alpha\leq T$ and that $$-\|T_{\alpha_0}\|\leq\|T_\alpha\|\leq\|T\|$$ for all $\alpha\geq\alpha_0$, but I don't know how to make this precise or mathematically rigorous. In particular, I just assumed $T_\alpha\leq T$, since this is natural for increasing convergent sequences of real numbers. I'm not really familiar with nets. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Some topology" is pretty vague, and for sure one can come up with pathologic topologies where $T$ is not even normal. But since the tag is "strong convergence", that's what I'll assume.

Indeed the net needs not be bounded. This is already true in dimension one: take $(T_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb Z}$, with 
$$
T_\alpha=\begin{cases} \alpha,&\ \alpha\leq 0\\[0.3cm] 1-\tfrac1\alpha,&\ \alpha>0\end{cases}.
$$
Then $T_\alpha\to1$, but the net is not bounded.

Regarding the tail, indeed from $T_{\alpha_0}\leq T_\alpha\leq\|T\|$ you can deduce that the tail of the net is bounded. For this you may use that 
$$\tag1
\|T_\alpha\|=\sup\{\langle T_\alpha x,x\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}. 
$$
From $(1)$ you see that $\|T_\alpha\|\leq\max\{\|T\|,\|T_{\alpha_0}\|\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How do you conclude that $T_\alpha\leq\|T\|$? (Or $T_\alpha\leq T$?)

Comment: You asked about the norm of $T_\alpha$. You have $\langle T_\alpha x,x\rangle\leq\langle Tx,x\rangle$.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness about the topology. I thought it was true for any topology, but I indeed needed the result for the SOT. Since the net is increasing, I understand that $\langle T_{\alpha_1}x,x\rangle\leq\langle T_{\alpha_2}x,x\rangle$ if $\alpha_1\leq\alpha_2$, but I don’t see why $\langle T_\alpha x,x\rangle\leq\langle Tx,x\rangle$ for all $\alpha$. I am missing something.

Comment: Since $T_\alpha x\to Tx$, the monotone sequence of numbers $\langle T_\alpha x,x\rangle$ converges to the number $\langle Tx,x\rangle$.

Comment: I know that a monotone convergent sequence (i.e. $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$) of real numbers is bounded by its limit, but is this also true for nets?